# Javascript: Custom toggle between classes in tab list without JQuery

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble correctly toggling classes in my tab list using javascript.

At first click the menu is open and on second click on the same will close, but after close will not open again if I click on the same menu.

Check my example to see exactly what I mean:

```js
var prev = '';
var tabsList = document.querySelectorAll('.main-col');

for (i = 0; i < tabsList.length; ++i) {

  tabsList[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('main-col');
  for (j = 0; j < elements.length; ++j) {
    elements[j].classList.remove("open");
  }

  var index = this.dataset.foo;

  document.querySelectorAll('[data-foo="' + index + '"]')[0].classList.toggle("open");

  if ( prev == this) {
    this.classList.remove("open");
  }

  prev = this;

  });

}
```

```css
h3 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
 
.main-col .menu {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .5s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1);
}

.main-col.open .menu {
  background: #333;
  max-height: 500px;
  transition: max-height .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="f-col1" class="main-col" data-foo="1">
    <h3 class="title-col1">Column 1 with sub-menu (1st click open, 2nd close and from now on will not open)</h3>
    <div class="column-1">
        <ul id="column-1-container" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-1" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 1</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 1</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="f-col2" class="main-col" data-foo="2">
<h3 class="title-col2">Column 2 with sub-menu (1st click open, 2nd close and from now on will not open)</h3>
    <div class="column-2">
        <ul id="column-2-container" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 2</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 2</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="f-col3" class="main-col" data-foo="3">
<h3 class="title-col3">Column 3 with sub-menu (1st click open, 2nd close and from now on will not open)</h3>
    <div class="column-3">
        <ul id="column-3-container" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 3</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 3</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

PS: Please don't give me alternatives with jQuery to this little problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE11 solution, with no polyfill (forEach)...

```js
let FcolsParent = document.getElementById("Parent_of_f-cols");

FcolsParent.onclick = function(e) {
    if (!e.target.matches('h3')) return;
    e.stopPropagation();

    let
      isOpen    = e.target.parentNode.classList.contains('open'),
      Open_Tabs = FcolsParent.querySelectorAll('.main-col.open')
    ;
    for( let i=0, iMax=Open_Tabs.length; i<iMax; i++ ) {
      Open_Tabs[i].classList.remove('open');
    }
    if (!isOpen) e.target.parentNode.classList.add('open');
}
```

```css
h3 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.main-col .menu {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
transition: max-height 1.5s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1);
  /*   transition: max-height 1.5s ease-in-out; */
}

.main-col.open .menu {
  background: #333;
  max-height: 500px;
  transition: max-height 1.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="Parent_of_f-cols">
  <div id="f-col1" class="main-col" data-foo="1">
    <h3 class="title-col1">Column 1 with sub-menu (1st click open, 2nd close and from now on will not open)</h3>
    <div class="column-1">
      <ul id="column-1-container" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-1" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 1</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 1</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="f-col2" class="main-col" data-foo="2">
    <h3 class="title-col2">Column 2 with sub-menu (1st click open, 2nd close and from now on will not open)</h3>
    <div class="column-2">
      <ul id="column-2-container" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 2</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 2</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="f-col3" class="main-col" data-foo="3">
    <h3 class="title-col3">Column 3 with sub-menu (1st click open, 2nd close and from now on will not open)</h3>
    <div class="column-3">
      <ul id="column-3-container" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 3</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 3</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this by the following:

```js
// Iterate each tab (main-col) that the toggle behaviour is applied to
document.querySelectorAll('.main-col').forEach(function(tabItem) {
  
  // Add click event listener to current tab to process toggle logic
  tabItem.addEventListener("click", function() {
    
    // Use the toggle method to toggle open class on and off
    tabItem.classList.toggle('open');
    
    // Select any currently open tabs, and remove the open class from tabs
    // that are not the tab we're currently toggling
    document.querySelectorAll('.main-col.open').forEach(function(openTabItem) {
      
      if(openTabItem !== tabItem) {
        openTabItem.classList.remove('open');      
      }
    });
  })
})
```

```css
h3 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
 
.main-col .menu {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .5s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1);
}

.main-col.open .menu {
  background: #333;
  max-height: 500px;
  transition: max-height .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="f-col1" class="main-col" data-foo="1">
    <h3 class="title-col1">Column 1 with sub-menu (1st click open, 2nd close and from now on will not open)</h3>
    <div class="column-1">
        <ul id="column-1-container" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-1" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 1</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 1</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="f-col2" class="main-col" data-foo="2">
<h3 class="title-col2">Column 2 with sub-menu (1st click open, 2nd close and from now on will not open)</h3>
    <div class="column-2">
        <ul id="column-2-container" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 2</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 2</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="f-col3" class="main-col" data-foo="3">
<h3 class="title-col3">Column 3 with sub-menu (1st click open, 2nd close and from now on will not open)</h3>
    <div class="column-3">
        <ul id="column-3-container" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 3</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 3</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the part that I have overlooked in my answer.

Comment: @DacreDenny, works perfect on modern browser, but can you modify it to work also on IE11. IE11 don't understand "forEach". I need it to work on IE11, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

what about if a click will happen on one of your link ?
actually this remove too your ".open" class

```js
    let FcolsParent = document.getElementById("Parent_of_f-cols");

    FcolsParent.onclick = function(e) {
        if (!e.target.matches('h3')) return;
        e.stopPropagation();

        let isOpen = e.target.parentNode.classList.contains('open');
        FcolsParent.querySelectorAll('.main-col.open').forEach( openTabItem=>openTabItem.classList.remove('open') ); 
        if (!isOpen) e.target.parentNode.classList.add('open');
    }
```

```css
h3 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.main-col .menu {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 1.5s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1);
}
.main-col.open .menu {
  background: #333;
  max-height: 500px;
  transition: max-height 1.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="Parent_of_f-cols">
  <div id="f-col1" class="main-col" data-foo="1">
    <h3 class="title-col1">Column 1 with sub-menu (1st click open, 2nd close and from now on will not open)</h3>
    <div class="column-1">
      <ul id="column-1-container" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-1" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 1</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 1</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="f-col2" class="main-col" data-foo="2">
    <h3 class="title-col2">Column 2 with sub-menu (1st click open, 2nd close and from now on will not open)</h3>
    <div class="column-2">
      <ul id="column-2-container" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 2</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 2</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="f-col3" class="main-col" data-foo="3">
    <h3 class="title-col3">Column 3 with sub-menu (1st click open, 2nd close and from now on will not open)</h3>
    <div class="column-3">
      <ul id="column-3-container" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 3</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 3</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item"><a href="#">LINK 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: MrJ can you make it work on IE11 please. IE11 don't understand "forEach" :(

Comment: the best for IE11 is to use a polyfill, the systems go out of fashion but the miles of codes exist for a long time.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill